# Selecting 'Region of Interest' based on color and also to identify the shape of the object

Tags: opencv, javacv, imagej

We have the following requirements for image processing:

1. A vehicle is present in the image. We need to isolate the area such that only the vehicle is visible i.e. becomes the region of interest and the rest of the area is either discarded / cropped.
2. where the area having a particular colour (an RGB combination, lets says yellow) has to be separated out / highlighted and then area has to be calculated for the same.

   I am new to OpenCV or ImageJ libraries which are used in these scenarios. Hence request to provide pointers on how to solve the problem.

Regards
Vijay

Comment: This has to be done for any image that is provided to the program i.e. no manual work should be involved

Comment: Your second requirement is not quite clear.
Do you want to highlight the colour of the object in the extracted region(like highlight the colour the car )  or do you want to highlight any region which is of a particular colour before you  perform grabcut algorithm.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this solution but just an idea.

1. Train a SVM or HAAR cascade classifier to perform [vehicle
   detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4LobbqeKZc)(car, motorbike, etc) in the image.
2. Result of detection can be given as an input to [grabcut
       algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOqOwM-Qbtg) which isolates the object of interest from rest.
3. You can highlight the area of particular colour based on its HSV colour components

Comment: We are using HAAR classifier and still working on the model to tune it to our requirements. However, the initial model is giving satisfactory results. Thanks